# Use HTTPs locally and in Server

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core project using HTTPS so I have on startup:

```
// In Configure method
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions(); 
rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToHttps();

// In ConfigureServices method
services.AddMvc(x => {
  x.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

Then on Program class I have the following:

```
  IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>();

  builder.UseKestrel(x => { 

    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");  

    if (env == "Development"))  
      x.UseHttps(@"../../local.pfx", "Password"); 

  });      

  IWebHost host = builder.Build();

  host.Run();
```

I am checking if the environment is Development to use the local certificate.

Otherwise it will use the certificate in the server (Azure in this case).

This is working both local and in Azure.

But should it be done this way?

Comment: Kestrel is normally ran behind a reverse proxy like IIS or nginx.  In such a case the SSL connection is handled by bthe reverse proxy.  And it's my understanding that the traffic from the reverse proxy to kestrel is over plain http.  So it seems odd to me that you are loading a cert into kestrel and having it handle https.  But perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. Even with the ssl handled by IIS or nginx your asp.net code can still redirect http requests to https as you are doing.

Comment: I found a few pages where they are doing something similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel (See the SSL part on bottom of the document); https://wildermuth.com/2016/10/26/Testing-SSL-in-ASP-NET-Core

Comment: The problem is that if I do as this posts show it will not work when uploading the application to the server since in there there will be a "real Certificate". So this is why I have this condition to test if the environment is Development. But it seems strange this is not mentioned anywhere ...

Comment: I see the first link you mention echos what I was saying "only your reverse proxy server requires an SSL certificate, and that server can communicate with your application servers on the internal network using plain HTTP."  Typically it's desirable to have the development environment match the production environment as closely as possible. So why not just configure IIS or nginx to handle the ssl and don't configure kestrel to do ssl, so dev is more similar to production?

Comment: Considering they've dropped configuration for Kestrel SSL in development from appsettings.json configuration in 2.0 https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1851, I think this is a good workaround.